# NetCDF: subtracting time steps

Tags: time, netcdf

I have a question regarding specific netCDF file manipulation. I am not sure how exactly to solve this issue.

I have a netCDF file that has 21 time steps and contains thickness data in the variable `lithk`.

I would like to substract the first time step from the last to get the change of the thickness between the first and the last time step.
Then I would like to get this newly calculated data added back to the netCDF file as a new variable.
I have tried many solutions and could not come up with the one that works so far. I would really appreciate any help on this.
Many Thanks

Comment: Please provide some info about what you have tried, what didn't Work.

Comment: What tool are you using for the manipulation of the netCDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose pseudosolution (you might have to modify this to match your need) in Python and using netCDF4 module and also NumPy for just in case.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import numpy as np
```

Now, I would open the netCDF file in write mode:

```
ncin = Dataset(your_file_in, 'a');
```

Then I would read the data:

```
datain = ncin.variables['lithk'][:];ntime=np.size(datain);
```

Now we can calculate the change between the first and last time step:

```
valout = datain[0] - datain[-1]
```

You want to write the new value to the file:

```
ncin.variables['lithk'][ntime+1:ntime+1] = valout;
ncin.close()
```

Beware, as I do not have your data and also I wrote the answer without testing, you might have to modify also the time variable and in order to change the number of data along time-dimension, it has to be 'unlimited'. Otherwise you just have to write a new netCDF file, where you change the time-dimension value to 22.

I can propose just some final example like this, where I first create random dataset in netCDF and make the adjustments like you wished:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
# -----------------------------
ndata=21;
dataout=np.random.random((ndata,));
unout='seconds since 2018-01-01 00:00:00'
# ---------------------
# make data:
ncout=Dataset('test.nc','w','NETCDF3_CLASSIC');
ncout.createDimension('time',None);
ncout.createVariable('time','float64',('time'));ncout.variables['time'].setncattr('units',unout);ncout.variables['time'][:]=np.linspace(0,3600*ndata,ndata);
ncout.createVariable('lithk','float32',('time'));ncout.variables['lithk'][:]=dataout;
ncout.close()
# ----------------------
# modify last value:
ncin = Dataset('test.nc', 'a');
datain = ncin.variables['lithk'][:];ntime=np.size(datain);
valout = datain[0] - datain[-1]
ncin.variables['lithk'][ntime:ntime+1] = valout;
ncin.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the way to go for sure. I get a ValueError when  I try to write the new value to the file. ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 194449 into shape (0,577,337). Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @Gernika: I assume based on your dimensions that you have 2D field for the thickness (actually 3D as time as well)? Otherwise I would not know why 3 dimensions. Nevertheless, as the error is  "cannot reshape ...(0,577,337)" means that there is no data along the first dimension. Can you check/show the outcome `ncdump -h your_inputfile` ?

Comment: Thanks! dimensions:
 time = UNLIMITED ; // (21 currently)
 y = 577 ;
 x = 337 ;
variables:
 float lithk(time, y, x) ;
  lithk:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;
  lithk:grid_mapping = "Polar_Stereographic" ;
  lithk:standard_name = "land_ice_thickness" ;
  lithk:units = "m" ;

Comment: @Gernika: in my example code, I found a mistake with the indices. There was `ncin.variables['lithk'][ntime+1:ntime+1] = valout` whereas it is supposed to be `ncin.variables['lithk'][ntime:ntime+1] = valout`. You could also show your code, how you are writing the output.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This seems to run with no errors. I am trying to write out this difference as a new variable with data = ncfile.createVariable('valout','float32',('time')). I can write it as a new netcdf file and then merge it with the original so both the original and the calculated thickness is in the same file. I am planning to use NCO's ncks for that. However, when I do that and check the file with ncdump  there are no values.